# How can I fill a pointer to array of structs where the only struct field is an array of unsigned char?

Tags: arrays, pointers

So far, this is what I've got:

Header file:

```
struct MyValue
{
    unsigned char   byData[8];
};
```

cpp file:

```
MyValue** values = new MyValue*[5];

void FillArray(void) {
    memcpy(&values[0]->byData, new unsigned char('98'), sizeof(unsigned char));
    memcpy(&values[1]->byData, new unsigned char('5'), sizeof(unsigned char));
    memcpy(&values[2]->byData, new unsigned char('78'), sizeof(unsigned char));
    memcpy(&values[3]->byData, new unsigned char('15'), sizeof(unsigned char));
    memcpy(&values[4]->byData, new unsigned char('9'), sizeof(unsigned char));
}
```

The first memcpy causes: `Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD`

Coming from a managed background, I'm not all that good at dealing with pointers, after a lot of googling around I got the idea from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

But I'm still stuck. I must have this somewhat weird structure because I'm trying to replicate the behavior of a third-party .dll which returns a pointer to an array of structs that contains this `unsigned char byData[8]` in it, but I seem to be completely lost.

This was my first attempt:

```
void FillArray(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        *values[i]->byData = i; //tried to force a cast, but access violation came before it
}
```

Which results in the same error. I have some insight about using the address of `&` operator and things like `*values` but I'm puzzled by this situation.

Comment: You forget `new` where they are useful, and put `new` where you shouldn't...

Comment: You have an array of pointers, but where do each of the pointers in the array point? Also, something like `'98'` is *not* a single character! Do you want to copy a string? Or the character whose [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) encoding is the *integer* `98`?

Comment: You might also want to check your operator precedence, because your "first" attempt was fine except for missing a couple of parentheses (or by not using explicit array indexing syntax).

Comment: `std::array<MyValue, 5u> values{{'9', '8'}, {'5'}, {'7', '8'}, {'1', '5'}, {'9'}};` may be what you really want.

Comment: Calling `new` in `memcpy` is going to leak like a sieve.

Comment: The major mistake you're making is trying to draw analogies between C++ and your "managed environment", which I'm certain is either Java or C#. Well, C++ is not C#, nor is it Java. C++ objects are fundamentally different from C# and Java objects. The best thing for you to do is to completely forget everything you know about objects, open a C++ book, and start reading from the first chapter. As long as you continue to try to make mental connections between C++ and what you already know -- which is understandable -- you will, unfortunately, end up being perpetually confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is allocation of memory. You have two dimensional array, but you allocated only one dimension.

This example is not tested, but I hope it will help you to undestand problem.

```
#include<new>
#include<cstdlib>
#include"myvalue.h"

MyValue** values;

void init() {
    values = malloc(sizeof(MyValue*)*5); // returns pointer to array of pointers

    *values = new MyValue[5]; // return five pointers to objects
}

void FillArray(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

        // !!! EDIT !!! there should not be derefference or arrow

        values[i]->byData = i; //this should work
        // *values[i].byData = i; //this should work too
}


int main() {
    init();
    FillArray();
    // do whatever you want

    // free memory from the last you created
    delete *values; // do not switch this
    free(values); // when switched, it cause memory error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Still not quite there, but I can see my mistake now. I'll try some stuff and let you know soon enough.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm not sure with `*values = new MyValue[5];` line, I just googled it. Usually I'm using for loop to initiate items one by one.The loop looks like `for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {values[i] = new MyValue;}`

Comment: Pointers are hard to understand and easy to make mistake (like my edit). Don't forget to use `delete` on what you created by new and use `free` on what you allocated by malloc.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm going with: `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { values[i] = new MyValue(); *values[i]->byData = i; }`. Thank you for the `free` tip as well, I usually only pair `new` with `delete`